# Extjs MVC folder structure can't load files

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I  want to use the extjs 4 framework to develop a Web application. 
It is my first contact with this framework so i started with the tutorials from Sencha. But there is one problem with the mvc tut and i can't find my fault.

At first I have to create following folder structure:

```
-account_manger
--app
--index.html
--app.js
--controller
---Users.js
```

But when I start the webside the developer tools from google chrome create this exception:

http://localhost/account_manager/app/app/controller/Users.js?_dc=1334940930898 404 (Not Found)

It seems like he is searching for another folder "app". But i don't now how i can change this.
Here is my code from the app.js:

`Ext.application({

name: 'AM',
appFolder: 'app',
controllers: [
'Users'],
....launch function etc..
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create following structure:

```
AccountManager
├── index.html
├── app.js
└── app/
    ├── controller/
    │   └── Users.js
    ├── view/
    │   └── Users.js
    ├── model/
    │   ...
    └── store/
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

AccountManager working demo here http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-mvc-application-architecture